# Issue using HttpParams

Tags: angular

> Angular Version: 4.3

I have a screen with 3 search fields: `id`, `name` and `category`. I do the research as the fields are filled out.

I would like a better suggestion for this code, because if I had several fields of research, it would be an impracticable implementation for the amount of combinations. The fact that the `HttpParams` object is immutable is that it is leaving me trapped in the field combinations, since I can not concatenate as I check if the field has been filled.

See the code below:

```ts
pesquisaRestaurantes(id ? : string, name ? : string, category ? : string): Observable < Restaurant[] > {
  let params: HttpParams = undefined;
  if (id) {
    params = new HttpParams().append('id', id)
  } else {
    if (name && category) {
      params = new HttpParams().append('name', name).append('category', category)
    } else if (name) {
      params = new HttpParams().append('name', name)
    } else if (category) {
      params = new HttpParams().append('category', category)
    }
  }
  return this.http.get < Restaurant[] > (`${MEAT_API}/restaurants`, {
    params: params
  })
}
```

I look forward to a better implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

...

```
 params = new HttpParams();

 If(name) params = params.append('name', name);

 If(category) params = params.append('category', category);
```

...

Comment: Já tentei esta alternativa, mas não funciona porque o objeto params é imutável. A partir do momento em que chamo pelo método .append ou .set, o objeto é clonado e devolvido esta nova instância somente com este último parâmetro informado.